# Этимология слова "шкодить"

Tags: этимология

Шкодить - значит, пакостить, вредить. А от какого слова оно образовано? И еще всегда было интересно, имеет ли к этому слову-понятию отношение название чешской фирмы автомобилей?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ШКОДИТЬ –  др.-рус. заимствование из польского языка, суф. производное от szkoda – вред, убыток. Шкодить – это причинять вред.

Автомобили марки «Шкода»   - это история  двух фирм.

История 1. 
 Название "Шкода" связано с Эмилем Шкодой (Emil Skoda). В 1866 г. Шкода был назначен директором небольшого механического завода в Пльзене, построенного еще в 1859 г. предпринимателем А. Вальдштейном (A. Waldstein). Позже он выкупил завод. Спектр продукции стал расширяться и был достаточно широким, со сбытом было тоже все в порядке, но Шкоде пришло в голову заняться броней. Он и в этом добился успеха, что определило направление развития завода на десятилетия. Сначала эта была броня, потом оружейное производство - корабельные башни с пушками. В мирное время паровозы, пивоваренное оборудование.

История 2.

Вторая история начинается с конца 1895 года. Механик Vaclav  Laurin и бухгалтер Vaclav Klement, оба увлеченные мотоциклисты, начали выпускать велосипеды собственной конструкции,  а затем мотоциклы. На рубеже веков компания предприняла еще один важный шаг, — был взят курс на производство автомобилей. Уже самый первый автомобиль, Voiturette A, созданный в 1905 году, имел коммерческий успех, тем самым став символом истории ЧЕШСКОГО АВТОМОБИЛЕСТРОЕНИЯ.  В ходе развития фирме стало тесно в рамках семейного предприятия. Пришло время перейти на новый уровень. В 1907 г. основатели преобразовали Laurin & Klement в акционерное общество.  Для укрепления и сохранения своих позиций, а также модернизации производства, L & K искали сильного партнера. В 1925 г. L & K вошла в состав крупнейшего промышленного предприятием региона, Skoda Pilsen. На этом закончилась история марки Laurin & Klement и появилась новая компания - Skoda.

Comment: Видимо, Skoda в свое время как-то нашкодил...)

Answer (score 3):

Скот
скот род. п. -а́, скоти́на, укр. скот, род. п. скота́, блр. скоцíна, др.-русск. скотъ "скот", "имущество" (Пандекты Никона), "деньги, подать" (часто в Пов. врем. лет, РП и др.; см. Срезн. III, 388), скотьница "казна", ст.-слав. скотъ κτῆνος, ζῷον (Еuсh. Sin., Супр.), болг. скот "скот", сербохорв. ско̏т, словен. skòt, род. п. skótа "детеныш животного, приплод", др.-чеш. skuot, skót (Ван-Вейк, AfslPh 36, 341), чеш. skot "крупный рогатый скот", польск. skot, в.-луж., н.-луж. skót, полаб. sküöt. Заимствование из герм. (ср. гот. skatts δηνάριον, μνᾶ, др.-исл. skattr "налог", др.-сакс. skat "монета, состояние", д.-в.-н. sсаʒ "denarius", нов.-в.-н. Schatz "сокровище") вероятнее, чем родство с герм. словами; см. Уленбек, AfslPh 15, 491; Стендер-Петерсен 309 и сл.; Янко, WuS I, 103 и сл.; Торп 448 и сл.; Кипарский 186 и сл.; Корш, Сб. Потанину 546. Принимая во внимание др.-фриз. sket "деньги, скот", Шварц (AfslPh 41, 126; ZfslPh 2, 115) предполагает лангобардско-варнский источник заимствования. Исконное родство гот. skatts и слав. skotъ (Младенов 585; Маценауэр 74) не исключено, но ср. о герм. названии денег Э. Шрёдер, KZ 48, 272. Марстрандер (у Кнутссона, ZfslPh 15, 129) видит источник герм. слов в кельт. этнониме Σκόττοι, напротив, Э. Леви (KZ 62, 263 и сл.) – в осет. skΏætt "хлев". И то и др. недостоверно. Явно неверно предположение о чередовании гласных скот : щети́на (откуда скот якобы имел первонач. знач. "свиньи"), вопреки Ильинскому (РФВ 73, 283 и сл.) Не может быть также речи о заимствовании из слав. в герм., вопреки Шрадеру (IF 17, 30), Брюкнеру (AfslPh 23, 626), Ягичу (AfslPh 23, 536), Преобр. (II, 310), потому что в этом случае герм. tt остается совершенно неясным; см. Фасмер, ZfslPh 4, 361; Кнутссон, ZfslPh 15, 128; Кипарский, там же. Др.-русск. знач. "налог, подать" некоторые ученые пытаются объяснить как частное заимствование из др.-исл. skattr (Томсен (Urspr. 135; SА I, 387), Кнутссон (там же)). •• [Якобсон (IJSLP, 1/2, 1959, стр. 271) тем не менее считает возможным родство слав. skotъ и щети́на и происхождение герм. skatt- из слав., причем герм. tt, по его мнению, передавало слав. t глухой смычный без придыхания. См. еще Трубачев, Слав. названия дом. животных, М., 1960, стр. 100–102. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Скот-сокращение от скотина.

Скотина--- в свою очередь идет от слова цена.

это сокращение от сколько цена.  Осталось в белорусском – скоцíна.
Скоко цена.

Так что все оговорки Фасмера против денежного смысла этого слова, цены не имеют.
В валлийском скот - Da Byw,  да был и всплыл, ну очень по нашему утаивать дань.

Шкодить. Шкода, Идет идет от слова  скот, с чередованием а-о в разных языках.

Вред, повреждение, ущерб –синонимы. Налог и дань-близкое смысловое-урон карману.
Вообще шкода -- общеевропейское.

Пройдемся по синонимам.
рассматривались три данных синонима-одинаковых по смыслу и некоторые другие типа
скот
скотина
бестия
шкот
повреждение
ущерб
урон
вред
налог
дань
убыток
щетина
кисти

итак
Вред, повреждение, ущерб, шкода.
В норвежском – skade
 Нидерландский - schade

Болгарский- щети              а вот и щетина- четина,  откуда пошло слово счет И щетка.
В  сербском щетина- четке-переводится как кисти. от четины – слова чет и нечет, и слово четыре. Возможно слово три. Пока вопрос и
в греческом щетина- τρίχες, А в каталанском,испания-щетина- truges.
урон- Έτοιμο—перекликается со словом стоимость и недоимок. 
От латинской щетины- setis никак в европу, а у нас от щетины-скота и шкоды—щедрость и жадность, щадить.
Немецкий - Schaden
Боснийский – šteta
Галисийский- danos         - дань
В гуджарати—почти санскрит—урон- nukasāna—ну как не сравнить с наказанием?
У них даже скотина от пасу –paśu,   ну и от кого кто набрался? 
Если налог- śrad'dhān̄jali –страдание, а скот—Paśudhana  слово хан и пасу от хана.

В каталанском все эти синонимы практически одни словом- danys 
danys 
done 
dany
в турецком- hasar   ---хазары, вот оно как!!
в латышском урон- cieņu   цена

а в македоском дань—это почет и уважение, разительная перемена в отношении, свой чужой.

А еще

шкот-storskøde- веревка, канат и морские термины. Датский и нидерландский.
Веревкой скот привязывали всегда.
В общем, не все веточки просмотрел, но и так все с этими словами ясно. Тут другой историей общеевропейской пахнет, индоевропейское утопия, больше смахивает на русскую экспансию в ранних средних веках, если не раньше.